# Get URL of the page in python

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My question might be bit weird.

So I have some page with different URL but all end up on same page. So Can I get that main URL from the old URL in python. For example:

```
1) https://www.verisk.com/insurance/products/iso-forms/
2) https://www.verisk.com/insurance/products/forms-library-on-isonet/
```

Both will end up on same page that is:

```
https://www.verisk.com/insurance/products/iso-forms/
```

So for each URL can I know the final URL where it'll land using Python(I have list of 1k URL). And I want another list of where those URL land correspondingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

```
import requests

def get_redirected_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)  # stream=True prevents fetching the actual content
    return response.url
```

This is a very simplified example, and in real implementation, you want to error handle, probably do delayed retries and possibly check what kind of redirection you're getting. (permanent redirects only?)

Comment: Thank you So much for Answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach with `urllib.request`:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
resp = urlopen("http://sitey.com/redirect")
print(resp.url)
```

Might want to use threads if you're doing 1,000 URLs...

Comment: Thank you So much for Answer!